# Editing Multiple Instances of a User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, instance, multiple-instances

I am semi new to C# and have made multiple instances of a User Control as such

```
StackPanel StkPnl = new StackPanel();
StkPnl = SP; //SP being the static objRef of the StackPanel in the MainWindow 
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    UserControl UsrCtrl = new UserControl();
    UsrCtrl = new UserControl1();
    UserControl1.TB.Text = "Text:"+i;   //TB being the static objRef of the textblock that is in the user control
    UsrCtrl.Name = "UsrCtrl" + i; 
    StkPnl.Children.Add(UsrCtrl);
}
```

What I am wanting to do is be able to call each user control i made independently and edit that specific textblock.text. eg: edit UsrCtrl3's textblock without altering the other 4 user controls created.

I found it kinda hard to explain myself. Let me know if you need any clarification and ill try to do my best to explain.

Comment: Do you mean subsequently target a specific user control in your collection to change its text, not just where you created them?

Comment: After each user control is created in the FOR loop, i would like to recall a specific user control that was created (lets say the third one created in the loop) and edit the textblock in that third UserControl. eg:

Comment: Yes Intracept, i couldent have said it better myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a specific element in a collection using the index like this:

```
StkPnl.Children[3].TB.Text = "Some Text";  // edit fourth user control (UsrCtrl3)
```

Or you can use LINQ to search on the name.

The method `SingleOrDefault()` expects at most one match. If no match is found, it returns `null`.

```
var thirdUserControl = StkPnl.Children.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "UsrCtrl3");

if (thirdUserControl != null)
    thirdUserControl.TB.Text = "Some Text";
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, and this may sound like a stupid question but when try to incorporate what you have said i get an error:

'System.Windows.UIElement' does not contain a definition for 'TB' and no extension method 'TB' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.UIElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)